# If $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of $x^2-3ax+a^2=0$, find the value(s) of $a$ if $\alpha^2+\beta^2=\frac{7}{4}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, quadratics

If $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of $x^2-3ax+a^2=0$, how do you find the value(s) of a if $\alpha^2+\beta^2=\frac{7}{4}$.

- I tried to substitute the $\alpha, \beta$ but confused since it is equal to $0$.
- Tried to expand $\alpha^2+\beta^2$. No clue here too.

How do you solve this?

Comment: Try to write down what $(\alpha+\beta)^2$ is equal to. . Can you express $\alpha^2+\beta^2$ using $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\beta$? (I will add that you can get $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\cdot\beta$ from the coefficients. Wikipedia: [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I did that. It becomes $(\alpha+\beta)^2-2ab$. But what do I do with it. I'm really lost.

Comment: Well, as already explained in an answer, if $x^2-cx+d=0$, you know both $\alpha+\beta=c$ and $\alpha\beta=d$, hence $\alpha^2+\beta^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta=c^2-2d$.

Answer (score 5):

Viète's relations give us $\alpha+\beta=3a$ and $\alpha\beta=a^2$, from which we get an equation in $a$:
$$(3a)^2-2a^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta=\alpha^2+\beta^2=\frac74$$
This simplifies to $7a^2=\frac74$ or $a^2=\frac14$, whence $a=\pm\frac12$.

Answer (score 3):

We know that: $\alpha+\beta=3a$ and $\alpha\beta=a^2$.
Now, $$(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta=\alpha^2+\beta^2$$ So,
$(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta=(3a)^2-2a^2=\frac74$

Now, just equate:

$7a^2=\frac74 \implies a^2=\frac14$, then $a=\pm\frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

No squaring: $${7\over 4}=\alpha^2+\beta^2 =(3a\alpha^2-a^2)+(3\beta -a^2) =  3a\underbrace{(\alpha+\beta)}_{3a}-2a^2 =7a^2$$

So $a=\pm{1\over 2}$.